# Send enhanced ecommerce data

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

When i land on the confirmation page i run the following code.

```
var purchaseObject = {
  'id': $OrderID,
  'revenue': $total,
  'shipping': $deliverycost
};
if (couponCode.length) {
  purchaseObject['coupon'] = couponCode;
}
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', purchaseObject);
ga('ec:send');
```

Both sends generates error messages.

> Plugin "ec" does not have method "send".

and

> Error calling a plugin method: {0: "ec:send"}

I have added

```
ga('require', 'ec');
```

in the head and the other events works so i don't get why the send does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EEC does not have a send method, you set the action with the E-Commerce-Data and this is send along with the next pageview (or other interaction). See the [example from the Google documentation:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#transaction)

```
// Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': 'T12345',
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online',
  'revenue': '37.39',
  'tax': '2.85',
  'shipping': '5.34',
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'    // User added a coupon at checkout.
});

ga('send', 'pageview');     // Send transaction data with initial pageview.
```

Notice the last comment - transaction is sent with the pageview. If you do not want another pageview, use an event.

Answer (score 1):

You can send it through an event:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});
ga('send','event','Ecommerce','Purchase','revenue', {nonInteraction: true});
```